# Is clique-width preserved under edge contractions?

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, cliquewidth

Let $G$ be class of graphs with bounded clique-width. In each graph in $G$ some edges are contracted (e.g. randomly). Is now the clique-width still bounded?

In case it is (in general) no longer bounded, I would be very interested in a counter-example.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This may be a pre-answer:
in [this 2007 arXiv paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0701185) (Problem 4.9), it is stated as an open problem whether one can find a graph $G$ and an edge $\{x,y\} \in E(G)$ such that $cw(G) < cw(G^{x,y})$, where $G^{x,y}$ is the graph $G$ with edge $\{x,y\}$ contracted.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! That is a valuable reference for me. In case no one has solved it in the meantime, my question is more or less answered :)

Comment: Isn’t that problem the opposite direction from what is being asked here?

Comment: Only in the sense that this question asks for a counterexample.

Answer (score 17):

This recent [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1306.6168) finally proves that edge contractions do not preserve the property that a set of graphs has bounded 
clique-width.